# How to set current window's width, in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension. 
I tried to get the current window then set its width, but it doesn't work ?

Here's the code in background.js:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(
    {populate: false}, 
    function(currentWindow) {
        currentWindow.width = 500;
    }
);
```

Ans here's the manifest.json:

```
{
    "name" : "windowresizer",
    "description" : "resize current window !",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "permissions" : ["tabs"]
}
```

Why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `chrome.windows.update` function:

```
chrome.windows.getLastFocused(
    {populate: false}, 
    function(currentWindow) {
        chrome.windows.update(currentWindow.id, { width: 500 });
    }
);
```

Comment: Save a function call by using `chrome.windows.update(chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, { width: 500 });` - see [`chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#property-WINDOW_ID_CURRENT). The [`chrome.windows.getLastFocused`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-getLastFocused) method might be a better choice than [`getCurrent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-getCurrent), though.